# xslt to remove single quotes from nodes in xml?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using xsl 1.0 version
I have this kind of xml
for example

```
<ss>'node1'</ss>
<ss1>'node2'</ss2>
```

Values are in single quotes. i want to remove those single quotes 
output should be

node1
node2

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '\&quot;', '')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

I tried this code, but no result. any suggestion would help
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&quot;` matches double-quotes `"`, not single quotes. You should use `&apos;`, although you will need to write it like so...

```
<xsl:value-of select='translate(., "&apos;", "")'/>
```

Also note your use of `\` is not needed, as this is not an escape character in xslt/xpath. (Unless, of course, your intention was to remove backslashes from the text too).

Answer (score 0):

Try `&apos;` instead of `&quot;`